# When I buid my app, it breaks because of my inputMask config

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd, extjs7

I am using sencha version 7.2. I have built an order form  and when running sencha app watch it builds fine. When I build it and run it from the build/production folder it breaks. I have narrowed it down to the inputMask I have set on the phone number, zip code, credit card, and expiration date. I am using this as I have always used it. With that said, this is also my first new project since updating to 7.2. Does anyone know if there is something I am missing or not declaring? Here is the 
[code for the address file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIVzZ.png). Here is the [code for main](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iDDB.png). The other files follow the same suit.

Comment: Please specify what you mean by "it breaks". Also please post a reproducible sample (as code) with your question so that someone can actually try to reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the documentation for Ext.field.Text from Sencha, in order to use an inputMask you must require 'Ext.field.InputMask'. I don't see that in the code you provided. Here's a [link](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.2.0/modern/Ext.field.Text.html) to the documentation, with the inputMask section in the configs. I also notice that you are using `emptyText: 'Zip Code'`, which could be changed to `placeholder: 'Zip Code'`.